# java.lang.NullPointerException when looking for Call Label?

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

Our app is getting a few error reports a week with this NullPointerException error on a onActivityResult(). We've tested it on many phones and have tried to fix our code but we are still getting reports from the Dev Console.

Here is the error:

```
  java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1001, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://com.android.contacts/data/612 flg=0x1 (has extras) }} to activity {com.package.app/com.package.app.PhoneLog}: java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:2536)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:2578)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2000(ActivityThread.java:117)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:965)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3691)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:847)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:605)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.package.app.PhoneLog..onActivityResult(PhoneLog.java:555)
at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:3934)
at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:2532)
... 11 more
```

I think there error is coming from where we get the Call Label from the onActivityResult() below:

```
     protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
             { 
                 super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data); 
                 if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                 switch(requestCode) {
                     case PICK_CONTACT:
                        // handle the contact result


                 Cursor c = getContact(data.getData()); 
                        if (c.moveToFirst()) 
                        { 
                            String name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("display_name"));
                           String num = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("data1"));
                           typeLabel = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("data2"));
                          long l = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("contact_id"));
                          c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("custom_ringtone"));


                         //error is here Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException             //at PhoneLog.onActivityResult(PhoneLog.java:555)
                          if(typeLabel.equals("1")) {
                                 typeLabel = "Home";
                              } else if(typeLabel.equals("2")) {
                                     typeLabel = "Mobile";
                                  } else if(typeLabel.equals("3")) {
                                         typeLabel = "Work";
                                  } else {
                                         typeLabel = "";
                                  }



                            callerName.setText(name);
                           callerNum.setText(num);
                          setChosenContactId(l);


                        } 
                     break;
    }
    }
    }
```

Comment: can you post what is on line PhoneLog.java:555\

Comment: Line 555 is   `if(typeLabel.equals("1")) {`

Comment: Why dont you just check for null at each if or just do the default action when you get typelabel as null. Some contacts might not have data2

Answer (score 0):

If the column "data2" can be null it explains the exception. A good pattern is to write the conditions as

```
"1".equals(typeLabel)
```

instead of

```
typeLabel.equals("1")
```

because the former works also for typeLabel == null.

Comment: So should I recode it like this:

`if(typeLabel  == null){
  typeLabel = "";
}   else if("1".equals(typeLabel)) {
                             typeLabel = "Home";
                          } else if("2".equals(typeLabel)) {
                                 typeLabel = "Mobile";
                              } else if("3".equals(typeLabel)) {
                                     typeLabel = "Work";
                              } else {
                                     typeLabel = "";
                              }`

Comment: If typeLabel being null caused the exception then this will solve the problem. You can skip the first conditional (check for typeLabel == null), because the case overlaps with the else-path, and typeLabel being null is no problem since equals() is called on the string literals ("1", "2", "3").

Answer (score 0):

Change to this hope it will work

```
 if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
             switch(requestCode) {
                 case PICK_CONTACT:
                    // handle the contact result

Cursor c = getContact(data.getData()); 
                   c.moveToFirst();

                        String name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("display_name"));
                       String num = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("data1"));
                       typeLabel = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("data2"));
                      long l = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("contact_id"));
                      c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("custom_ringtone"));

                       c.moveTonext();
                     //error is here Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException             //at PhoneLog.onActivityResult(PhoneLog.java:555)
                      if(typeLabel=="1")) {
                             typeLabel = "Home";
                          } else if(typeLabel=="2")) {
                                 typeLabel = "Mobile";
                              } else if(typeLabel=="3")) {
                                     typeLabel = "Work";
                              } else {
                                     typeLabel = "";
                              }



                        callerName.setText(name);
                       callerNum.setText(num);
                      setChosenContactId(l);



                 break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe Your Cursor is null?
That is if getContact(data.getData()); crashes and returns null.

I cant see the implementation of the method, so I cant be sure, but I would suggest checking for NULL before trying to access the cursor.